# Does `bazel run` use sandboxing? If not, why not?

Tags: bazel

From my tests, it doesn't appear that `bazel run` runs in a [sandbox](https://bazel.build/docs/sandboxing). For example, I ran `bazel run //:some_target --spawn_strategy=darwin-sandbox --sandbox_debug`, and it didn't generate a new directory in `<outputBase>/sandbox/darwin-sandbox`.

Am I correct that `bazel run` doesn't use sandboxing? If so, why not?

Answer (score 1):

`bazel run` will build the target you pass with sandboxing and caching the same way as `bazel build`, and then it will run it outside the sandbox. That's the whole point of `bazel run`.

If you want to run a command inside the sandbox, write a [genrule](https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#genrule) and then `bazel build` the genrule target.